# How to test a cron job?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 10.0.4.  I want to run a script every 6 hours, every day.  When I issue `sudo crontab -e`, I see:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* 00,06,12,18 * * * /opt/scripts/selenium/run_nis_inf_tests.sh
```

However, I'm not seeing the expected outcome from my script, and I'm not even sure if its running.  Is there a way to test, short of waiting until the specified time, that the script is running properly.  Or, how can I view the errors the script is generating? - Dave

Comment: You should also take care about the cronjob's filename and avoid underscore or extensions. For example on the Ubuntu mother (eg Debian), I faced that issue as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486601/linux-debian-crontab-job-not-executed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the MAILTO variable to your email address, and cron should email you any STDOUT and STDERR output. Also check your syslog file /var/log/messages to see if the script is being executed by cron.

-Tony

Comment: Is there always a success/failure message written to /var/log/messages?  If so, it contains nothing about my cron, which would indicate it isn't running.  I haven't got email set up on my machine yet, so I'll give that a go and see what shakes out.

Comment: There is nothing written to /var/log/messages but adding a MAILTO variable above the crontab line gives the feedback I was looking for. - Dave

Comment: in a debian system the default log is /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 1):

Cron should mail it results so it looks like you have a problem.
Here, it seems you are missing a user to run the script as :

```
00,06,12,18 * * * user_name /opt/scripts/selenium/run_nis_inf_tests.sh
```

replace user_name by the name of the user the script needs to be run by, verify permissions of "run_nis_inf_tests.sh" and you should be ok.

Comment: When I tried your suggestion (adding the username), I got the error, "/bin/sh: selenium: not found".  The syntax I use is, "00 */1 * * * /opt/scripts/selenium/run_nis_inf_tests.sh".

Comment: Yes sorry, no username needed in your case as you do crontab -e ! Did you check syslog.conf ?