# How to schedule a cron job to run from 11PM to 6AM

Tags: unix, cron

I have a python program which i need to run from 11PM (EDT) to 06AM (EDT). How can I schedule a cron job to do this.

```
* 23-6 * * 1-5 python my_program.py
```

will this work? or do I have to write 2 seperate cron jobs for this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837615/how-to-test-a-cron-job

Comment: Thanks. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204037/how-to-schedule-a-cron-job-to-run-from-11pm-to-6am/204041#204041    this helped me. seems like the above cron scheduling will only run.