# ISPConfig 3.0.4.1 Does not create web folder or .conf when adding website

Tags: web-hosting

I am using ISPConfig 3.0.4.1 and when I go to add a new site I am successful in that it appears on the websites tab but it does not actually create the web## folder in the client folder on my server when I SSH into it. It's not a matter of it creating it in the wrong client folder or anything, it just doesn't create the folder at all. I also added the DNS zone for the domain but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

has to do something with *cron* bug in Debian/Ubuntu: ISPconfig works by setting various cron jobs to do the work.

there is some solution to that on http ://www. howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=38675

and on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/238755

also, read this [linux debian crontab job not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486601/linux-debian-crontab-job-not-executed)

=======

after some research, it seems that it has something to do with an imutable bit:

http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=60767

Comment: please try to post the solutions here and link the reference at the end .. these links might not be around in 20 years or so ! welcome to stack overflow.